# Can't send data from my custom IOS App using BLE Shield 2.1 to my Arduino Uno

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno

I am currently working on designing a snake-like robot that will be controlled via a custom Iphone iOS app.
I am using the following technologies:
- Arduino-Uno
- Adafruit Motor Shield
- Nema 17 Bipolar Stepper Motor
- BLE Shield 2.1 from RedBearLab

My iOS app includes a slider, such that when the slider moves, a stepper motors speed will be controlled. I am using a Write function in xcode to send the speed data to my arduino, but when I try to print the read results in my Serial Monitor, the data is just 0.

```
func writeSpeed(_ speed: UInt8)
{
    // See if characteristic has been discovered before writing to it
    if let positionCharacteristic = self.positionCharacteristic
    { 
        let data = Data(bytes: [speed])
        self.peripheral?.writeValue(data, for: positionCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse) //with originally
        print(data)
        print(speed)
    }
}
```

When I print the data and speed it's results look as follows...

```
1 bytes
3
1 bytes
4
1 bytes
3
1 bytes
2
end sliding
```

My Arduino code is as follows...

```
// Add in necessary libraries
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <boards.h>
#include <RBL_nRF8001.h>
#include <RBL_services.h>

SoftwareSerial BLE_Shield(9,8);  // Configure the Serial port to be on pins D8 and D9. This
                               // will match the jumpers on the BLE Shield (RX -> D8 & TX /> D9)

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 

// Define the stepper motor attached to the motor shield.
// i.e. 200 steps per revolution (1.8 degree) in motor port #2 (M3 and M4)
  const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;
  const int motorPort = 2;
  Adafruit_StepperMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 
motorPort);

void setup() 
{ 
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  BLE_Shield.begin(9600);   // Setup the serial port at 9600 bps. This is the BLE Shield default baud rate.
  ble_begin();

  // Initialize serial port at 9600 bps
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Print a ready statement to serial monitor          
  Serial.println("Stepper Motor is Ready!");

  // Stepper motor
  AFMS.begin(1600);  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz
}

void loop() 
{ 
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  ble_do_events();
  if(BLE_Shield.available()) 
  {
    Serial.println("Available");

    // Read the value of the slider and store it in the variable data
    int data = BLE_Shield.read();        //Read the incoming data & store into data
    Serial.println("The data from iphone is...");
    Serial.print(data);

    // Eventually sliderData will be a variable, but for now, a constant
    const int sliderData = 30; 

    // Specify the speed of my stepper motor
    myMotor->setSpeed(sliderData);  // 30 rpm
    Serial.println("Speed is 30 rpm");
  }

  else
  {
    Serial.println("Stopped working");
  }

  //ble_do_events();
  delay(500);
}
```

I really don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: What output do you get from the Arduino code?

Comment: @Paulw11 the Arduino output was ...
 Stepper Motor is Ready!
 Evt Device Started: Setup
Available
The data from iphone is...
0Speed is 30 rpm
Evt Device Started: Standby
Advertising started
Available
The data from iphone is...
0Speed is 30 rpm
Available
The data from iphone is...
0Speed is 30 rpm
Available
The data from iphone is...
0Speed is 30 rpm
Available
The data from iphone is...
0Speed is 30 rpm
Available

And then it just keep repeating from there.

Comment: Does it keep repeating even when your iOS app isn't running?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, it does. Even when it start up the App, and move the slider, the Arduinos output doesn't change. It repeats like that for maybe 10-20 seconds and then automatically goes to outputting "Stopped working"... i think because the software serial library automatically stops being available after it doesn't receive data for an extended period fo time.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to check the setup on your Ardunino; Do you have the right baud rate?  Do you have the right connections?

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry, correction: when i close the app, the arduino outputs "Stopped working". I don't think the connections are the problem, because I am only using the Arduino cable connected to my laptop, plus the BLE shield has all proper solder connections. I think I am inaccurately trying to read the Iphones data, although i beleive my code is accurate.

Comment: Are you sure about the baud rate?  You could try the LightBlue App from the App store; connect to your device and send data onto the right characteristic.  Your iOS code looks OK

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the Tip, i'll try downloading the LightBlue App, i'm not near my arduino though, so will have to test it out later today!

Comment: @Paulw11 Downloading the app helped a lot, I figured out that I had mixed up the RX and TX characteristics, so it runs great now. Thanks again!